# How to Enable Authority CA Root in Google Chrome Ubuntu through command line?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, ssl-certificate, puppeteer

In google chrome on Linux I can goto Settings>Certificates>Authority>Select a CA root and Hit Edit to trust/Enable it. By default it is disabled and complains ERR_INVALID_CERT_AUTHORITY. Need to run chrome in headless mode and also ubuntu without X Windows so it has to be done on command line. I have added my client certificate using pk12util -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -i [path_and_name_to_PKCS#12_file.p12] and certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L shows me my client certificate installed correctly.